# Getting value from a custom object exception error

Tags: vb.net, properties, propertyinfo

When I try to assign _val I get "Object does not match target type."

I verified both PropertyInfo's are system.string.  I also found examples of this syntax.   Thanks for any help.

```
Private Function SetAttributesForSplitFiles(ByVal _file As String, ByVal _depHeader As HeaderParse)
    Dim _fileMask As New FileMaskExtension()
    Dim _type As Type = GetType(HeaderParse.depBackupFileProperties)
    For Each _prop As Reflection.PropertyInfo In GetType(OutputMgr.Interface.FileMaskExtension).GetProperties()
        Dim _headerProperty As PropertyInfo = _type.GetProperty(_prop.Name)
        Dim _val = _headerProperty.GetValue(_depHeader)
        _prop.SetValue(_fileMask, _val, Nothing)
    Next
    SendFileTODepcon(_fileMask, _file)
End Function
```

Comment: For a start, you haven't defined the type of **_val** e.g. **Dim _val as Integer**. Set a breakpoint at that line and hover you mouse over **_val** to see what type the IDE thinks it is and then hover over **GetValue** to see what type it should be. Then define **_val** as the appropriate type and if needed, convert **_headerProperty.GetValue(_depHeader)** to an appropriate type

Comment: Oh, and in the Visual Studio settings, **ALWAYS** set **Option Strict** to **On**. It will pick up these kind of errors. There are only a very few reasons to have it turned off.

Comment: I added Option Stict ON  but I still get the error.

Comment: I added this line of code

Comment: Dim _val As Object = _headerProperty.GetValue(_type)

Comment: What type does the getvalue property return? You would be far better declaring _val as that type. Working with object types isn't a good idea unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: I forgot to ask - does the error occur on the line we've been talking about or a different one?

Comment: There are about 20 properties in it with different types that why I was working with Objects or when I had opt strict off,  letting it inherit the type.

Comment: Yes the error happens on what the line where _val is assigned.

Comment: Ouch! Good luck! I mean that.

Answer (score 0):

It was because the custom class I was using was two layers deep.

This worked.

```
Dim _val As Object = _headerProperty.GetValue(_depHeader.FileProperties)
```